# Set default values in FromJSON

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'd like to set default value for a model I have

```
-- models
Bid
    price           Int
    created         UTCTime
    user            UserId
    deriving        Eq Show Generic
```

I'd like the `user` property to be set by the current user, but the following doesn't work:

```
instance FromJSON Bid where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
     Bid    <$> v .: "price"
            <*> getCurrentTime -- "created" property.
            <*> requireAuthId -- "user" property.
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

However, It doesn't compile, and I'm not sure how to populate both the `created` and `user` default values.

Comment: Are you trying to do some `IO` while you are decoding `JSON` (get the time and get some authentication)? Maybe you should try to separate the `JSON` decoding from the `IO` you need to do in order to create your model. You could create an intermediary model for the `JSON` object.

Comment: Oh, you mean have a bare bones `SemiBid` with just the `price` and then in my handler - build a full `Bid` with all the `IO` properties?

Comment: Well with `price` and whatever comes from `JSON` really. You should have in Haskell a type that represents exactly the kind of values you expect your `JSON` parser to ever encounter. Nothing more! If you are only interested in a subset of the values coming from `JSON` that's fine, only parse the ones you are interested in. Then if you want to use this data as part of a bigger model, create that logic in Haskell without thinking about `JSON`. You need to decouple the different concerns :-)

Comment: What do you mean by parse only the ones I'm interested in? You mean to make them optional in FromJSON, and the override them in my handler? 
Also, I've tried another smaller type and it works nicely. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I don't know what `JSON` model you are working with, but often there is data that is not of any interest for your application. In that case there is no need to create a field for it in the Haskell representation of that `JSON` object. This is what I meant. If you created the `JSON` model yourself and have exactly all and just the fields you need then by all means: parse them all! :-) For most simple `JSON` parsing I would recommend using the Template Haskell functions from aeson. It makes it really easy and pain-free to parse and generate `JSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up, thanks to the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300050/set-default-values-in-fromjson#comment73666036_43300050) by @basile-henry

```
--Models.hs

-- A Bid type that represents the data we will get from JSON.
data SemiBid = SemiBid
  { semiBidPrice :: Int
  }

instance FromJSON SemiBid where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
     SemiBid <$> v .: "price"
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

And then in my `POST` handler:

```
postRestfulBidsR :: Handler Value
postRestfulBidsR = do
    currentTime <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    userId <- requireAuthId

    semiBid <- requireJsonBody :: Handler SemiBid
    let bid = Bid
          { bidPrice = semiBidPrice semiBid
          , bidCreated = currentTime
          , bidBidder = userId
          }

    bidId   <- runDB $ insert bid

    -- ...
```